# About generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

```
def fib(max):
    n, a, b = 0, 0, 1
    while n < max:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b
        n = n + 1     
    return 'done'

print(next(fib(6)))
print(next(fib(6)))
print(next(fib(6)))
```

the result is `1，1，1`.
However, if I change the content in `print()` as below:

```
f = fib(6)
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
```

the result will be `1, 1, 2`. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Pls post the actual indentation?

Comment: You create new generators each time. You do see that difference, don't you?

Comment: You might also want to remove the 'done' following your return statement...

Comment: @Rawing thank U for your advice.Thanks to Jim who had already helped me improve my question. I will notice it next time:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `print(next(fib(6)))` always creates a new instance of the `fib` generator and yields one value from it, you then discard it.

On the other hand:

```
f = fib(6)
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
```

creates an instance `f` of the generator `fib` and yields three values from it.

Also, using `max` as the parameter name is frowned about since, in the local scope at least, you're masking a built-in function that has the same name.